# How to manage a "no-path" scenario with A*

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graph, a-star

I have AI with A* scripts on a 2D grid with no weights. What is the ideal or typical way of managing a "no-path" situation with these AI, e.g. where the AI are blocked from their end target by unwalkable tiles? I can see capping the open list, but this seems arbitrary--after all a path to a target can be quite long--but what is the typical way of approaching this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the A* should have a limit on how much iterations it should perform. There is no "default limit" that you could use because you can use multiple strategies to test for this.

**TLDR**: Use [Divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) to simplify the solution to smaller problems for the best result, and limit your A* to confined space, or iteration amount.

Listed from the worst to the best.

1. **Set hard limit** - This is the simplest solution and the worst at it best. Because you do not know where is the issue, or if the path is walkable or not and it's hard to decide what you should do if you reached your path limit.
2. **A* from start and finish at once** - Doing this "should" not increase the performance of the algorithm, and if the paths meet you have an answer. But if they don't, you can track where was to the closest point between the start and finish, and go set it as the "temporary destination". Then try again from there (you can save the path you got already and expand it from there). The drawback of this approach is that you can go the wrong way in some edge cases.
3. **Low-quality A* for graph waypoint pathfinding** - If you know that some places have a long route that it might take a long time to find a route, you can chunk the world map - and calculate the route based eg: 32x32 or 64x64, etc. chunk as a single node in A*. Create an algorithm that checks if this chunk is walkable. Then instead of making the whole route using A*, use Dijkstra's algorithm that would predetermine path using predefined waypoints (preferably generated before runtime), and then use A* to move inside the chunk that would target walkable grid element in another chunk. This way you know how to get into the same chunk as your destination, and from there a penalty for discovering that there is no path inside the chunk is minimal, as you have a very limited area to check.

Answer (score 1):

If there are never any walkable paths between two tiles there is no reason for them to be part of the same graph. If the map is static you can pre-process the map into into sections that are guaranteed to have valid paths between all tiles using Djikstra.

If the map is fully dynamic you probably have to set a hard upper limit the number of nodes.

If only specific nodes can be blocked/unblocked you might want a multi-level strategy.  I.e. create a node for each section and run a preliminary path finding in this graph.

Another solution would be needed for things like nodes being blocked by NPCs, for example by disregarding them during path-finding and handle conflicts when they occur.